# How to set the classpath while generating a jar in Intellji Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have generated a jar using Intellji Idea but it throws a compile error: Could not find or load main class com.xxx.xxxxx

I guess it was caused by I did not explicitly set the class path in manifest properties. Any idea how to do it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run jar file: Could not find or load main class Hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774012/cannot-run-jar-file-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-hello)

Comment: @racraman thanks, but not really.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the sample project.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks but I need set the classpath not add an external library.

Comment: Do you need to set classpath or the main class? Are you sure it's a compile error and not runtime error?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've set the main class already. Not sure whether is compile error or run time error.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's a runtime error if you get it when attempting to run the jar (eg by "java -jar xyz.jar").  I'm going with it being a runtime error :)   The fact the error has the full package "com.xxx.xxxx" means the full package name has been picked up, so further classpath issues in the manifest shouldn't be a problem.  Maybe check that the classes are in the jar (eg just rename to ".zip" to do so), as per the answer I linked to : "You need to specify that you want to add the compile output to the jar or else it will only have the manifest and not your actual classes. "

Comment: @ racraman Thanks, I changed it to zip file and  find there is only one file :MAINFEST.MF. Do you know why? I follow the steps in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly/4901370

Comment: Use a build tool such a Maven or Gradle don't generate artefacts using your IDE directly. Intellij is a professional development tool and as such expects you to use professional development practices. If you want to learn to code, use an IDE designed for learning not an IDE designed for getting stuff done.

Comment: The module you've added may not have any compiler output, check the content and source roots for the module you are using in the artifact.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks. I am not quite sure how to check compiler output. I rebuild the projects and it runs ok but I cant run the jar for same issue. I tried maven approach which throw an exception.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html. Make sure the module you've added to the artifact has source roots which produce the output classes.