# Couldn't find or load main class when running jar file

Tags: java, packaging, manifest.mf

I know this is a common issue, but i've tried many things to make this work.

Main Class name: **Test**

I've included a `MANIFEST.MF` with `Main-Class` attribute, as follows:

1. `Main-Class: src.client.Test`
2. `Main-Class: classes.client.Test`
3. `Main-Class: client.Test`
4. `Main-Class: Test`

None of the above worked.(the `jar` is located in the **deploy** dir )

This is the contents of my project:
[image]

On my deployment profile i have included:

1. `MANIFEST.MF`
2. **lib** directory
3. All the merged content of the file's group contributor (`Test.class` , an **external** `jar` that i'm using )

Note: I'm using **JDeveloper 12c** IDE

---

Related posts i've tried but i couldn't make it work:

[Could not find or load main class with a Jar File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030675/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-with-a-jar-file/13030952)

[Cannot run jar file: Could not find or load main class Hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774012/cannot-run-jar-file-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-hello)

Comment: Can you please post the exact exception you get? May be its an unresolved dependency that causing main to fail loading? Will need full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned correctly the `Main-Class` attribute, although the `Class-Path` **was wrong**.

---

The structure of the `.jar` file is the following:

`myjar/client/Test.class`

`myjar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

`myjar/myexternal.jar`

---

I Had to mention `myexternal.jar` in my `MANIFEST.MF` as follows:

**Correct**: `Class-Path: ../myexternal.jar`

**Wrong** : `Class-Path: myexternal.jar`

I don't know if that is making any sense, i shouldn't get an exception loading the main class because of the wrong way of mentioning `myexternal.jar`

Nevertheless this fixed it!

Comment: From what I understand both are wrong. It's simply not possible to specify a jar contained in other jar that way for plain java. Maybe there is a working ..\myexternal.jar existing relative to the code base from which the containing application was loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You jar should have the following structure:

```
  yourjar.jar
  |-client
  | |-Test.class
  |-com
  | |-external
  |   |-package
  |     |-SomeClass.class
  |     |-SomeOtherClass.class
  | ....
  |-META-INF
    |-MANIFEST.MF
```

And your MANIFEST.MF file should contain

`Main-Class: client.test`

Comment: Should i pack it  by using `java` command? I'm trying to do it with an automated way through the IDE

Comment: still, it doesn't recognise the `Main-Class` , i have the exact structure you mentioned (except the `com/external/package` etc)

Comment: This is really odd, if i extract the `jar` in the same `dir` and do `java -jar myjar.jar` it runs! It works if only the `external.jar` and `myjar.jar` are in the same `dir` . How is this possible? (even if i delete `Test.class` from my `dir` it stills runs my `myjar.jar`(
`myjar.jar` contains `external.jar` , `client`  , `META-INF`)